# Scrolling adds values to textviews

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have created an app that keeps track of course information. At the moment the only field that Changing dynamically is the `modcode`, the rest of the fields are all hardcoded to input the number 1, for now.

This is the insert code:

```
public boolean insertData(String ModCode,String ModDesc,int UniID,int FacID,int EduID,int NoOfTest,int NoOfAss,int NoOfPrac,int NoOfExam)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(Col_2,ModCode);
    contentValues.put(Col_3,ModDesc);
    contentValues.put(Col_4,UniID);
    contentValues.put(Col_5,FacID);
    contentValues.put(Col_6,EduID);
    contentValues.put(Col_7,NoOfTest);
    contentValues.put(Col_8,NoOfAss);
    contentValues.put(Col_9,NoOfPrac);
    contentValues.put(Col_10,NoOfExam);
    long result = db.insert(Table_Name, null, contentValues);
    if(result==-1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;

}
```

and the front end side of insert:

```
db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
textModCode = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textModCode);
button_add = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_add);
AddData();
```

The button press:

```
public void AddData(){
    button_add.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v){
                   boolean isInserted = db.insertData(textModCode.getText().toString(),"1",1,1,1,1,1,1,1);
                   if(isInserted=true)
                       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Data in",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   else
                       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Sorry",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   refresh();
                }
            }
    );
}
```

Refresh:

```
public void refresh()
{
    Cursor res = db.getAllData();
    moduleList = new ArrayList<>();
    if (res != null ) {
        if  (res.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Module m = new Module(res.getInt(res.getColumnIndex("ModID")),res.getInt(res.getColumnIndex("NoOfTest")),res.getInt(res.getColumnIndex("NoOfAss")),res.getInt(res.getColumnIndex("NoOfPrac")),res.getInt(res.getColumnIndex("NoOfExam")),res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("ModCode")),res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("ModDesc")),res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("UniID")),res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("FacID")),res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("EduID")));
                moduleList.add(m);
            }while (res.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    /*
     */
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    moduleAdapter = new ModuleAdapter(this, moduleList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(moduleAdapter);
}
```

The recycler view displays everything right at first, but after scrolling the numbers begin to change with each scroll up or down.

When first open
[image: first view]
1st scroll down and up
[image: second view]
2nd scroll down and up
[image: thirdview]

did I do anything wrong or what is going on? Thank you or any help

ModuleAdapter Class code

```
public class ModuleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ModuleAdapter.ModuleViewHolder>{


private Context mCtx;
private List<Module> moduleList;

public ModuleAdapter(Context mCtx, List<Module> moduleList) {
    this.mCtx = mCtx;
    this.moduleList = moduleList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ModuleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx);

    View view = inflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.module_list, parent, false);
    return new ModuleViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ModuleViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Module module = moduleList.get(position);
    holder.textModCodeView.setText(module.getModcode());
    holder.textModuleDescView.setText(module.getModdesc());
    holder.textEducatorView.setText(holder.textEducatorView.getText()+ module.getEducator());
    holder.textNoOfTestView.setText(holder.textNoOfTestView.getText()+ String.valueOf(module.getNooftest()));
    holder.textNoOfAssView.setText(holder.textNoOfAssView.getText()+ String.valueOf(module.getNoofass()));
    holder.textNoOfPracView.setText(holder.textNoOfPracView.getText()+ String.valueOf(module.getNoofprac()));
    holder.textNoOfExamView.setText(holder.textNoOfExamView.getText()+ String.valueOf(module.getNoofexam()));

    Random r = new Random();
    int red=r.nextInt(255 - 0 + 1)+0;
    int green=r.nextInt(255 - 0 + 1)+0;
    int blue=r.nextInt(255 - 0 + 1)+0;

    GradientDrawable draw = new GradientDrawable();
    draw.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
    draw.setColor(Color.rgb(red,green,blue));
    holder.textModCodeView.setBackground(draw);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return moduleList.size();
}

class ModuleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView textModCodeView,textModuleDescView,textEducatorView,textNoOfTestView,textNoOfAssView,textNoOfPracView,textNoOfExamView;
    public ModuleViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        textModCodeView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textModCodeView);
        textModuleDescView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textModuleDescView);
        textEducatorView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textEducatorView);
        textNoOfTestView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textNoOfTestView);
        textNoOfAssView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textNoOfAssView);
        textNoOfPracView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textNoOfPracView);
        textNoOfExamView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textNoOfExamView);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: post your **ModuleAdapter** class code

Comment: I think the problem is in `ModuleAdapter`

Comment: I will post it now

Comment: @GowthamanM There you go

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko There you go

Comment: it works exactly the way you requested: `holder.textEducatorView.setText(holder.textEducatorView.getText()+ module.getEducator());`What did you expect this line to do?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Thank you, see the mistake now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this steps

1.Clear you arraylist before adding all values  `moduleList.clear();`

**Refresh:**

```
public void refresh()
{
    moduleList.clear();   // add this line
    Cursor res = db.getAllData();
    moduleList = new ArrayList<>();
    if (res != null ) {
        if  (res.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Module m = new Module(res.getInt(res.getColumnIndex("ModID")),res.getInt(res.getColumnIndex("NoOfTest")),res.getInt(res.getColumnIndex("NoOfAss")),res.getInt(res.getColumnIndex("NoOfPrac")),res.getInt(res.getColumnIndex("NoOfExam")),res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("ModCode")),res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("ModDesc")),res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("UniID")),res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("FacID")),res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("EduID")));
                moduleList.add(m);
            }while (res.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    /*
     */
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    moduleAdapter = new ModuleAdapter(this, moduleList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(moduleAdapter);
}
```

2.change below code as i mention below (i think view get conflit)

```
 holder.textEducatorView.setText("Educatore"+ module.getEducator());
    holder.textNoOfTestView.setText("NoOfTestView"+ String.valueOf(module.getNooftest()));
    holder.textNoOfAssView.setText("NoOfAssView"+ String.valueOf(module.getNoofass()));
    holder.textNoOfPracView.setText("NoOfPracView"+ String.valueOf(module.getNoofprac()));
    holder.textNoOfExamView.setText("textNoOfExamView"+ String.valueOf(module.getNoofexam()));
```